# How to apply Test Driven Development with Django Models?

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing, tdd, django-testing

I've recently learned about Test Driven Development and want to give it a shot while developing a new app in my Django project. I've been reading [Test-Driven Development with Python](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754) which is great. However, I've sometimes found the example (To Do lists) in the book to be too simple- for instance, when [testing Models is introduced](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch05.html#_the_django_orm_and_our_first_model), the author has a test that creates to objects, saves them, and then pulls the objects from the database to check their values. Sure, that's easy when your model only has one ModelField.

But what about when your model has twenty ModelFields? Should you have one test that creates an object, with all of its Fields, then saves that object, and then checks the value of each field? Is it better to make individual tests for each field?

In my specific case, I have a model with about five required fields, and then about fifteen more fields that are optional. My thought right now is to first have a function within my TestCase class that creates an object of this Model with the default fields. Then, I will have a test to make sure that object saves normally, and then another test for each individual optional field. Seems like a lot of tests, but isn't many small tests better than one large test?

Insight appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am the author of said book.  I meant that test as more of an introduction to the Django ORM, rather than as a demonstration of best practice, and I try to explain that at the time, but I suppose some confusion was inevitable.  I'll have a think about how I could present things differently.

In any case, if you skip along to [a few chapters later](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000000754/ch12.html#_rewriting_the_old_model_test) in the book, I show how to simplify the test to something that's more best-practicey.

Whether or not you test basic Django models is up to you -- some people will say testing a declarative syntax is over the top, others will say a short test is good to have as a placeholder.  Here's one you might use:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ForeignKey(Author)
    ISBN = models.CharField(max_length=35)
    abstract = models.TextField()


class BookTest(TestCase):

    def test_defaults(self):
        book = Book()
        self.assertEqual(book.title, '')
        self.assertEqual(book.author, None)
        self.assertEqual(book.ISBN, '')
        self.assertEqual(book.abstract, '')
```

So that's a placeholder.  It encourages you to add more tests if you start introducing more complex fields like, say, a `publication_date` field which has a default value of `datetime.today() + one_month`, which might warrant a bit of testing to make sure you get it right.  Having a placeholder lowers the barrier to subsequent tests.  Other people will tell you that's over the top.  You have to find your own balance.

One thing that's pretty widely accepted is that you should definitely test behaviour.  So, if your model has a custom method:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    # [...]

    def is_available(self):
        return self.pub_date < datetime.today() and Stock.objects.filter(book=self).count() > 0
```

Then some sort of test for that is definitely a good idea.

Comment: Haven't read your book, but have watched 2 of your TDD Tutorials. The Oreilly TDD Webcast, and 2013 Pycon (To which I went). Im getting ready to watch some more of your talks on TDD. I have to say you've done a great justice by releasing so many tutorials on TDD.

Answer (score 1):

This is where model factories would help a lot. There are two popular modules that provide it:

- [`model_mommy`](https://github.com/vandersonmota/model_mommy)
- [`factory_boy`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

I've personally used `factory_boy` and find it very easy to use.

Basically, you define a factory with default field values:

```
class UserFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = models.User

    first_name = 'John'
    last_name = 'Doe'
    admin = False
```

Then, you can [use the factory](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#using-factories) and override field values if needed. It also supports [Sequences](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#sequences), [Lazy Attributes](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#lazy-attributes) and other useful features for generating the data.

Speaking about your particular task, try not to test what django actually has tests for. For example, there is no need to test whether `required` argument works. Test your custom model logic involved in manipulating the model.

Also, [`A Guide to Testing in Django`](http://toastdriven.com/blog/2011/apr/10/guide-to-testing-in-django/) is a good read.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but in speaking specifically with the test driven development approach, I believe that I shouldn't write code until I have a test for it, right? So if I want to have a ModelField on my Model, I must have a test for that, no? It's not that I want to test whether `required` works, it's that I want to test whether or not the field itself works on my Model. I.e, if I create an object and set that field, and save it, does it come back out? Yes in a way this tests Django, but it also provides design and test for my Model itself.

Comment: @Joseph correct, strictly speaking, if you want to follow the TDD approach entirely, then yes, before adding a new field on a model, you need to write a test for it, see it failing, add field and see the test passed. But, personally, I usually don't go so deep. Time is valuable and there are usually more important things to test. This is just my point. And I love testing, really.

Comment: Thanks, I think for now I'll proceed without going that far, like you mention. I've heard that TDD requires some kool-aid drinking, so I wanted to give it an honest try, even where that includes things that *seem* like they make more work or waste time- ideally the payoff is that time and work is saved later. Thanks for your help, and I appreciate the link to A Guide to Testing in Django.

Comment: @Joseph great, thank you. I also recommend watching Carl Meyer's presentation on [`Testing and Django`](http://pyvideo.org/video/699/testing-and-django). Also, there are [other great videos](http://pyvideo.org/search?models=videos.video&q=testing+django) on `django` and `testing`. Let me know if you need any further help. Happy testing!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you test the saving and loading of values to the database? That's Django's responsibility. Django has a whole suite of tests that check in detail that its database layer is working. There is absolutely no reason to check the basic behaviour of any of your fields, let alone all of them.

Your unit tests are for your logic: your custom methods, your views, your template tags. They are not for logic that is provided by Django by default.

Comment: As mentioned on the other answer, I am specifically referring to Test Driven Development, not "regular" testing of my Django application. Like @alecxe confirmed, truly following the TDD approach requires tests before code, even for something as simple as a ModelField.

Comment: It's not so much testing saving & loading of values, but rather have you chosen the correct fields & properties on those fields.  For example, if you have a field on your model called ```account_number``` that has to be unique, there should be a test to make sure you've written your model to correctly add the ```unique=True``` property on that field as that's a business requirement that should be enforced by tests.